# uploaded image not display in redirected jsp page still refreshing it again

Tags: jsp, servlets, netbeans

I am creating a web application in JSP SERVLET using netbeans 8.0.1
I am uploading an image file in my project folder's i.e. "MyApplication/web/images/MyImages/" directory    It will upload image successfully and redirect to page where i want to show that image.

But the even after it redirects to success.jsp it does not showing image still I refresh it again.

so please tell me what to do to see images by redirecting page (i.e. no need to refresh it).

Comment: where is the code? How do you expect us to help you if you dont provide enough information?

Comment: please show us the code

Comment: My uploading code is woriking fine  I have problem in displaying image in my jsp page.
in that i use code:
String picPath = request.getServletContext().getContextPath()+"/images/MyImgs/"+img.jpg;
<img src="<%=picPath%>" />
It will not display until I refresh it manually by pressing f5